# OpenGL: Как проверить, создан ли контекст?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

Как проверить, создан ли OpenGL контекст без всяких API кроме самого OpenGL?
A хочу чтоб в функции загрузки текстуры была проверка: если контекст есть - делаем все как обычно, а если нет - только загружаем текстуру, а потом когда будет создан контекст, генерируем opengl текстуру. Иначе, если контекста нет - получится ошибка сегментации.

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Если ты создал клнтекст и он не вернул кода ошибки, то наверно он создан ..

Comment: При загрузке текстуры, мне надо знать это. Если контекста нет, произойдет ошибка сегментации.

Comment: Так а кто создает контекст, и кто получает код ошибки если он не создался?

Comment: Я ) Но я пишу либу не только для себя, поэтому, я хочу чтоб в функции загрузки текстуры была проверка: если контекст есть - делаем все как обычно, а если нет - только загружаем текстуру, а потом когда будет создан контекст, генерируем opengl текстуру.

Comment: Стоит добавить все эти уточнения в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть это будет полезно, вы можете проверить какой текущий контекст для данного потока. Функция [wglGetCurrentcontext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374383(v=vs.85).aspx)

В Linux может быть вам подойдёт функция [glXGetCurrentContext](http://opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXGetCurrentContext.xml)

Comment: Я не пользуюсь Windows. А в linux такой функции нет.

Comment: Может быть вам подойдёт функция glXGetCurrentContext: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXGetCurrentContext.xml

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!